# Rootpage error xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

My root page is giving error by clicking on the back, instead of being in the background, an unhandled error occurs "An unhandled exception occurred. Is something wrong with my command?
[image]

I made the following attempt, when I call other pages besides Rootpage, the error does not occur

```
public class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    Dictionary<MenuIndex, NavigationPage> Views { get; set; }

    public RootPage()
    {
        Title = "teste";

        Views = new Dictionary<MenuIndex, NavigationPage>();

        Master = new MenuPage(this)
        {
            Icon = "ic_menu_white.png"
        };

        NavigateAsync(MenuIndex.Page1);
    }

    public void NavigateAsync(MenuIndex id)
    {
        Page newPage;

        if (!Views.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case MenuIndex.Page1:
                        Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new Page1(), "#04518c"));
                    break;
                case MenuIndex.Page2:
                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new Page2(), "#04518c"));
                    break;
                case MenuIndex.Page3:
                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new Page3(), "#04518c"));
                    break;
                default:
                        Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new Page1(), "#04518c"));
                    break;
            }
        }

        newPage = Views[id];

        if (newPage == null)
            return;

        //pop to root for Windows Phone
        if (Detail != null && Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
        {
            //await Detail.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }

        Detail = newPage;

        if (Device.Idiom != TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            IsPresented = false;
    }

    //comand example
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't put any Nav logic in a Page constructor because there is no guarantee the VIews have completed initializing.  And in any case where you get an unhandled exception, you need to figure out what the actual exception message is before doing anything else.

Comment: As can be seen in the image (edited above) the error occurs at the time of sleep

Comment: What is the ACTUAL EXCEPTION causing the crash?  Do you understand how to figure that out?

Comment: How to do this has some documentation so i can do this

Comment: Start by placing a try/catch around the suspect code so you can capture the error message in the debugger or by writing to the console.  Alternately, you should be able to break into the debugger from the Unhandled Exception dialog and view it.  Finally, there are numerous posts on SO about dealing with unhandled exceptions in Xamarin

Comment: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Use google.  That is a very common Android error message and likely has nothing to do with your crash.  I've given you several suggestions and it doesn't appear that you've listened to any of them.